# What would happen if I suddenly suck air on water?

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics, vacuum

In a condition that there is a closed tank with water in it, and also there’s some air on that water. Tank is closed.

Somehow(let’s say through a very thin hole) if I vacuum the air on the water from tank suddenly, what would happen to the water?

I think the water would get sucked, vacuumed because there was air on it, but now it vanished suddenly, so there’s no air pressure acting on its top surface. However, there is still air pressure among the water molecules at bottom.

For this unbalanced force equilibrium,
Water would be vacuumed, sucked, in my opinion.

Do you agree?

Answer (score 3):

The density of the air would decrease and with it the pressure of the air would drop. The pressure of the water would also drop. The pressure of the air and the water should be the same at the surface. The pressure of the water below the surface follows $p=p_s+\rho_wgd$, where $p_s$ is the pressure at the surface, $\rho_w$ is the density of the water and $d$ is the depth below the surface.

So the overall pressure of the water would also drop, but water expands/contracts very little when the pressure changes. The water level would stay approximately the same.

As the pressure of the air drops, more and more water will start evaporating. At some point the pressure would be low enough that the water starts boiling. Since we are still sucking from the top, this will continue until all the water has turned to gas. After this, all the water vapour will be sucked up until we end with a vacuum.

This setup is not too different from having a glass of water in a vacuum chamber. You should be able to find videos of this on youtube if you are interested.

---

Edit: for this I assumed the tank is emptied relatively slowly. If you violently sucked out all the air, there would be a strong air current towards the hole. Some of the water might get sucked up like this. But most likely only a small part of the water will get sucked up like this, after a short while the tank should settle and we would have situation like I described above.

Comment: So in general, you agree with me on it that if the air on the water gets vacuumed suddenly, there will be a vacuum force applying on the water  to be pulled towards air current. 

If the air on water vanishes, water tends to go up due to unbalanced forces at that instant. 

Do you agree?

Comment: @Jawel7 Yes, there will be a short-lived upwards force that will severely shake up the water.

Comment: @Jawel7 I think you should read this answer more carefully. The reason the water gets sucked into the vacuum eventually is that it boils and becomes a gas. This is completely different from your unbalanced forces description, which is incorrect. No liquid water will enter the vacuum - in case that wasn't clear. You should try to understand the reality here, and not twist words to make it sound like your initial idea was kind of right in some strange way.